# Magento 2 : Custom template file is loading after refreshing the page only?

Tags: magento2, template-override

Here is my code for overriding vendor module template. when the page corresponding to this layout loads, it is fetching template file from vendor.after the refresh it is fetching from my custom module.Please help.

```
<referenceBlock name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">My_Sales::order/create/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below layouts are to be overrided.

- sales_order_create_index.xml
- sales_order_create_load_block_items.xml
- sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml

Comment: Hi, did you find anything to resolve this, im facing the same issue. Magento version: 2.3.1

Comment: i added respective code to all the above xml files and finally issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should  put this in module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Sales" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>          
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Its depends which module you trying rewrite file

Comment: I have already added Magento_Sales, dependent module in module.xml.
Issue is when the page loads and displays,the changes done in custom template file is not getting reflected. after refreshing the same page, the changes are reflecting.

Comment: maybe first time it was cache?

Comment: i tried enabling template hints and checked.on first load,it shows vendor folder template file.then after refresh it showed custom module template.

Comment: This happens alternatively on each refresh

Comment: what is the magento version?

Comment: try this 
 <referenceBlock name="items" template="My_Sales::order/create/items.phtml" />

Comment: Version 2.1.5, i tried this.still issue persists.

Comment: disable cache and test one more time

Comment: i tried disabling the cache.No luck :(