# Magento 2 - Add custom form to admin sales order create

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, xml

I'm trying to add a form to the admin sales order create page.
When I create a new order i cannot see my form but if i refresh the page the form is available.

i added code to sales_order_create_index.xml (Vendor and Module names changed)

```
        <referenceBlock name="data" template="Vendor_Module::order/create/data.phtml"/>
    <referenceContainer name="data">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\GeodisCarrierService" template="Vendor_Module::order/create/geodis_carrier_service.phtml" name="geodis_carrier_service_block"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

where data.phtml is basically the original file with one additional line that loads the block

```
   <?= $block->getChildHtml('geodis_carrier_service_block') ?>
```

the geodis_carrier_service.phtml code:

```
<section class="admin__page-section geodis-info">
<div class="admin__page-section-title">
    <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Geodis Information')) ?></span>
</div>
<div class="admin__page-section-content">
    <fieldset class="admin__fieldset " id="geodis-carrier-service">
        <legend class="admin__legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Geodis Carrier Service')) ?></span></legend>
        <br>
        <div id="carrier_service_block" class="edit-carrier-service">
            <div class="order-history-block">
                <div class="admin__field field-row">
                    <div class="admin__field-control">
                        <select name="order[geodis_carrier_service]" id="geodis_carrier_service" class="admin__control-select">
                            <?php foreach ($block->getCarrierServices() as $value => $label): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($label) ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049033/magento-add-block-to-sales-order-create

[Magento 2 : Custom template file is loading after refreshing the page only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261602/magento-2-custom-template-file-is-loading-after-refreshing-the-page-only)

https://theonlinehelper.com/blog/add-custom-message-to-admin-sales-order-view-invoice-and-credit-memo-in-magento-2/

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-block-shipping-billing-address-admin-sales-order-view-page-magento-2/

[Custom Module's template override not loading initially unless the page is refreshed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287829/custom-modules-template-override-not-loading-initially-unless-the-page-is-refre)

[Adding new block in admin order section](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268279/adding-new-block-in-admin-order-section)

From the above links I understand that I also need to add some code to this files:
sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml
sales_order_create_load_block_items.xml
to make it load the form right from the start and not only when i refresh the page
but i just don't understand what code should those files contain.

Has anyone built a module like this and can prodive insights ?